# Laravel add foreign key to a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to add a permission_id foreign key to my users table which shall reference the id in my permissions table. Currently I built following Migration:

```
<?php
class AddPermissionIdForeignKeyToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('permission_id')->after('id');
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('permission_id');
        });
    }
}
```

But I get following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`eyes`.`#sql-22f0_3dd`, CONSTRAINT `users_permission_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `p   ermissions` (`id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint
>   `users_permission_id_foreign` foreign key (`permission_id`) references
>   `permissions` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> In PDOStatement.php line 144:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`eyes`.`#sql-22f0_3dd`, CONSTRAINT `users_permission_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `p   ermissions` (`id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE)
>
> In PDOStatement.php line 142:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`eyes`.`#sql-22f0_3dd`, CONSTRAINT `users_permission_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `p   ermissions` (`id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already data in your table users you need to declare your field permission_id as nullable.

`$table->unsignedInteger('permission_id')->nullable()->after('id');`